# Best way to communicate between an Android App and a JavaFX Application

Tags: java, android, sockets, javafx

I am working on a JavaFX music player which can communicate with an Android App via TCP Sockets, displaying some Data from the music player (e.g.: Playlist). The Android app loads a list of all available music players from a database. In this list there is also the the current IP and the current PUBLIC_PORT of the music player. Then the Android app can connect to the player over the TCP socket and the PUBLIC_PORT. After that the music player returns a "PRIVATE_PORT" to the Android app (so that the app can communicate over the PRIVATE_PORT with the player), and starts listening for new clients to connect.

```
    public void connectToServer() {
    boolean end = false;
    for(int i = 0; end == false; i++) {
        try {     
            if(i > 100) {
                end = true;
            }
            socket = new java.net.Socket(serveraddress,port);

            end = true;
            port = Integer.parseInt(getPortFromServer());
            Log.d("", "Connected to engine on port" + port);
            socket.close();
            socket = new java.net.Socket(serveraddress,port);
            readPlaylist();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
    } 
}
```

Because i think this is not a very good solution, because i need alot of TCP ports i was wondering if there is any better method to implement this.

My only idea for a different implementation is a RESTful webservice, but i am sure if this would work, because i am using JavaFX and i need an executable file to launch the music player without installing a Webserver.

EDIT: Another idea would be putting a Webserver between the Android app and the JavaFX player. This way i would solve the PORT problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by using UDP Sockets.